# как отправить текст из edittext main activity в edit text second activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

как отправить текст из edittext main activity в edit text second activity?для kotlin не  java. я новичок поэтому не знаю java можете пример показать пожалуйста! с помощью shared preference.

Comment: А в [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) нельзя посмотреть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще у вас есть несколько вариантов отправки, и SharedPreferences не является совсем идеальным для вашей задачи как мне кажется, либо вы предоставили неполную информацию. Начнем с SharedPreferences так как вам нужен именно этот вариант. У вас есть поле для ввода и вам нужно взять с него текст:

```
var editTextHello = findViewById(R.id.editTextHello) as EditText
val text = editTextHello.text
```

дальше вы сохраняете данные в память как было указано в [комментариях](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences):

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getSharedPreferences("your_storage", 0)
sharedPref.edit.putString("text_from_field", editTextHello.text).commit()
```

дальше в активности где вам нужно получить эти данные, вы их вытаскиваете:

```
 val sharedPref = activity?.getSharedPreferences("your_storage", 0)
val text = sp.getString("text_from_field", "")
```

так же есть и второй вариант - использовать Intent для передачи данных из активности в активность, при условии что эти данные нигде больше не будут задействованы кроме как в процессе данной передачи. В активности с полем для ввода текста:

```
val intent = Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("text", editTextHello.text)
startActivity(intent)
```

и дальше извлекаем этот текст:

```
var : String = intent.getStringExtra("text")
```

Comment: Andrew можешь пожалуйста тогда еще написать как перекинуть данные из edit text в другой edit text second activity без shraed

Comment: После получения данных из другой активности у целевого поля делайте что-то типа `edittext.setText(text)` вот есть такой вариант - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493908/setting-text-in-edittext-kotlin. Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.